# What is a replacement part for GOBO 21411?

Tags: plumbing, shower, faucet

My shower has a mixer valve capsule whose only marking is GOBO 21411. You can see it in the pictures attached below.

[image: Can see marking here GOBO 21411]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thus far I know that ["DANCO Cartridge for Glacier Bay Single-Handle Tub/Shower Faucets | Works for Hot & Cold Water Applications | Faucet Repair (10321)"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005JTHTS8) does **NOT** replace it, as I bought it and it's bigger than the capsule.  What is the right replacement part, or aftermarket part for this?

Googling tells me GOBO is Glacier Bay, but I have no idea if that's right.

Here is a picture of the shower faucet mount,

[image]

Comment: Take the old one shopping with you and compare side-by-side.

Comment: I did, to three home depots.

Comment: Maybe you should try an actual plumbing supply store instead. They'll actually know what they're talking about and will have a _significantly_ larger inventory and knowledge base.

Comment: Agree with FreeMan. This kind of thing is something you'd buy from a plumbing supply house.  BigBox stores are only really good if you already know exactly what you want and happen to be lucky enough to have them carry it. Home Depot is likely to only carry the 10 most popular ones...or fewer.

Comment: You can buy it online, I self answered this question @gnicko.

Comment: I've voted to reopen this question. Since I'm not looking for anything and it'll help a lot of people. It's self-answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part that I bought that replaced this was

- [DANZE DA603566 Washerless Cartridge Square Stem for 1H Tub & Shower, Brushed Nickel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002P8TN0S).

It comes with the ["Seats and Springs"](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/255726/5778). But this didn't ultimately solve my problem with the water not mixing: it did solve my problem with the faucet handle leaking. I ended up having to replace "Pressure Balance Spool". I used

- [DANZE DA507041 Pressure Balance Spool](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000VZP4G4)

Which worked in the picture above, this is the larger bolt head to the immediate right of the faucet handle.