# What do they call these rubber items and springs in a faucet?

Tags: faucet

These items came out when I tried to change my shower water-mixing capsule, what are they?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

They're called "Seats and Springs", you can find them for your manufacturer or you can buy a variety pack.

- The rubber piece is called a "seat"
- The spring is just a "spring", or seat spring.